# Which Microcontroller can I use on a Arduino board?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega

I own a [Arduino UNO](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) with the **ATmega328** Microcontroller.
Which other Microcontrollers are compatible to the Arduino system?

Comment: This is the link to Atmel AVR 8 bit: http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/devices.asp?category_id=163&family_id=607&subfamily_id=760

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several varieties of Arduino available. All are based on the Atmel AVR 8 bit microcontrollers.

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Hardware

The UNO has a DIP socket which can support the ATMega8, ATMega168 or the ATMega328. See [this thread on the Arduino forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=107.0) for more detail.

Comment: So "Atmel AVR" is a specification for Microcontrollers?

Comment: Yes, Atmel are a semiconductor company who make a range of microcontrollers. Their AVR microcontrollers use their proprietary AVR core. The AVR's have a different instruction set to other processors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set

Comment: That thread points to [this page](http://www.avr-developers.com/cputable.html), which lists a number of Atmel micros that have been made to compile/work under the Arduino software, including AT90CAN, AT90USB, ATtiny models, and, of course, ATmega - 40 different micros in all (59 when you differentiate -p part numbers).  It might be good to incorporate some of the info from that thread in your answer.

Comment: @reemrevnivek I took the question to mean "what chips can I put in my Uno". If you include everything with some level of Arduino compatability, you could go as far as the Maple and other ARM based boards... Maybe even the Papilio AVR soft core...

Answer (score 2):

Generally Arduino (if not all) use Atmel AVR 8-bit MC's.
Which IMO is a good thing since I find them personally easier to use (and they are usually cheaper too).

Not that PICS are bad or anything...